# nullPointer Exception on Asset manager

Tags: android, asset-management

I have this function in my class Activity :

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String strName) {
    AssetManager assetManager =this.getAssets();
    InputStream istr = null;
    try {
        istr = assetManager.open(strName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    return bitmap;
}
```

this function is in public class Game1 extends Activity

but I get nullpointer exception on :

```
AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at packagename.Game1.getBitmapFromAsset
```

what should I do?

Comment: may be `this` is null. in which file you had kept this method ?

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace, and indicate where in your code you are calling `getBitmapFromAsset()`.

Comment: I used context or getbaseContext() instead of this but it didnt work :(

Comment: Please post stack trace as CommonsWare suggested.

Comment: Is this method getBitmapFromAsset() in non-activity class??

Comment: thanks... you are right... I have called the function including 'this.getAssets' before OnCreate()!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `getBitmapFromAsset()` after the activity is created.
If you call it before the activity creation then it will give `NullPointerException`.

The code then -

```
AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
```

Here the `this = getActivity()` and therefore is null.

Answer (score 0):

First create a context as below,

```
Context mTestAppContext = getContext().createPackageContext("com.project.test",
                Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
```

here, use your package name instead of "com.project.test". And use above context instead of "this" shown as below,

```
AssetManager assetManager = mTestAppContext.getAssets();
```

Hope above can help.

Comment: what if we write getApplicationContext() instead of getContext() ?